# jQuery css method with 3 parameters

Tags: jquery

I came across a line of code using jQuery css method as below

```
var $container = $('#mycontainer');  <br>
var w = $.css($container[0], "width", true);<br>
```

jQuery documentation on css method was checked and didn't mention any variant with 3 parameters. I test the code in jsbin and it worked fine - return value is a number. if the last parameter was changed to `false`, the return is a string like `200px`.

could anyone highlight me on this special syntax on method css?

Is it something deprecated ?

Comment: +1 for pointing out that subtle difference. Might come in very handy getting the raw string version (which the element version does not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just the static version of `css`, not the jQuery *element-specific* instance version, so it also needs the object to apply it to.

The normal version would look like this for the code shown:

```
   $container.css("width");
```

So you can see the static version just moves the target element into a first parameter. Otherwise how would it know what to apply the style too :)

`true` is not really a valid value for "width", so it looks like the static version uses that as a flag to say whether to return the value as a string (with the suffix px) or as a value.

Comment: thanks! just more question : in this case, what's the meaning of the second boolean parameter (true)?

Comment: `true` = Return as number (removes the px), `false` = return as original text.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the source code of the `jQuery.css` method. I didn't look into much of the details, but it seems, that there is the `extra` parameter, which changes the output format in combination with a `cssHook` defined specially for the `width` property.

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/css.js#L302-L334

Comment: Argh... No... He pulled back the curtain... IT'S NOT MAGIC AFTER ALL!  :)